# Upload file blob php

Tags: php, download, blob

I need help for upload blob file.

I have this code:

```
echo "<tr><td>File document:</td>";echo"<td>";
echo '<a href="download_file.php?FileDocument=' . $show['id']. '">Open file</a>';
```

i need help next code.
I already tried various codes and none worked.I just need a code from the simplest

```
<?php

include("connect.php");
if (isset($_GET["id"]) && ctype_digit($_GET["id"])) {

$sql = mysql_query("Select * From tb_work where id = $id");

 if ($sql) {

    if (mysql_num_rows($sql)==1) {


        $line = mysql_fetch_row($sql);


        $file = $line['FileDocument'];


        if ($file!='') {


            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
            header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
            header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
            header('Content-Length: '.filesize($file));


            echo $file;
          }
       }
    }
  }
  ?>
```

the result this is blank page

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried thus far?

Answer (score 0):

You try to use `$_GET["id"]` but there is no `id` parameter in your url, only `FileDocument`.
Try `$_GET["FileDocument"]`.